# Como imprimir em impressora matricial no cliente com uma aplicação web?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, impressão

Tenho uma aplicação feita em C# MVC com uma rotina pra imprimir um texto simples na impressora padrão. Foi utilizado o método `RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter` que está descrito neste [artigo](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/kb/322091).
A impressão ocorre normalmente quando rodo a aplicação localmente, mas quando publico no servidor, ela lista as impressora instaladas no servidor e não no cliente.

Como eu faço para que a aplicação pegue a impressora do cliente e não do servidor? Caso não seja possível, como eu abro então a caixa de dialogo de impressoras pela aplicação .NET C# MVC 4?

```
    public bool ImprimeConteudoDiretamenteNaImpressoraPadrao(string conteudo)
    {
       string nomeImpressoraPadrao = (new PrinterSettings()).PrinterName;
       return RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(nomeImpressoraPadrao, conteudo);
    }
```

Comment: Da uma olhada nessa resposta do soEN http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501910/retrieving-clients-printer-collection-in-asp-net

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 6):

Cliente é cliente, servidor é servidor. Por razões que deveriam ser óbvias não é possível acessar recursos do cliente através do servidor. O servidor só consegue enviar textos e outros dados para o navegador decidir o que fazer.

Mesmo no cliente só o usuário pode decidir se a impressão será realizada. Um código em JavaScript pode iniciar o processo para depois o usuário decidir. Não dá para fazer mais que isto.

```
window.print();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Browser/Print.js).

Aplicações web não são solução para tudo.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver meu problema da seguinte forma. Instalei os drives da impressora matricial no servidor web e defini o nome da impressora instalada diretamente na aplicação, desta forma funcionou sem problemas, a impressora pode estar na rede ou instalada local no cliente.

```
string conteudo = "Teste impressão";
string _nomeImpressora = "EPSON FX-890 ESC/P";
RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(_nomeImpressora, conteudo);
```

Comment: Se isso resolveu o problema porque deram -1 pra resposta? Não entendi

Comment: @Marcelo a resposta certa para a pergunta não é necessariamente "boa".